# why this binary search tree can't be a red black tree?

Tags: algorithm

I had a question that asked to explain why this balanced tree can't be a red black tree and also wanted to transform it into a red black tree using only one rotation:

[image: The image of the balanced tree]

Why can't this binary search tree be a red black tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a red-black tree, every path through a leaf has the same number of black nodes, and at least every second node on the path will be black, since a red node can't have a red child.  Therefore, the longest path to a leaf in the tree (the one with the most red nodes) is at most twice as long as the shortest path to a leaf.

17 -> 11 -> 3 -> 5-> 7

has more twice as many nodes as

17 -> 19

so this cannot be a red-black tree.

If you rotate right at the root, then the tree will be more balanced and could be colored as a red-black tree.

Answer (score 0):

Property 5 of [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) is violated.

> Every path from a given node to any of its descendant NIL nodes contains the same number of black nodes.

Given that the root is black, the path to the nils at the end of 7 are imbalanced with respect to the path to the nils at the end of 19.  19 has 1 black node to traverse; 7 has about 3.

This tree can't be considered a red-black tree since it's not properly balanced.

Comment: first of all thanks for your help ,How to fix it to be a red black tree using one rotation only ?

Comment: You...can't.  That defeats the purpose of the red-black tree algorithm.  You don't just rotate the tree and suddenly it becomes balanced.  You have to actually go through the steps and ensure that it *is* balanced.

Answer (score 0):

As other's have explained if

17 & 19 were both black, then the path 17,11,3,5,7 breaks the black height. If every other node was red-black-red etc, then 17 (black), 11 (red), 3 (black), 5 (red), 7 (black) would have 3 black nodes where as the path 17,19 would have 2 black nodes.

But suppose 7 as a node did not exist. Then the remaining tree could be a red-black tree:
[image: Tree before 7 was added]

And suppose 7 was inserted. Then with some color flipping and a right rotation about 17 you get
[image: Tree after 7 was added]